# Stripping external punctuation from elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, strip, punctuation

I have a list of lists of strings:

```
master_list = [['my', 'fellow', 'citizens.'], ['forty-four', 'americans', 'have', 'now!', 'taken', 'the', 'presidential', 'oath.']]
```

and I want to strip the non-internal punctuation from each entry leaving me with

```
new_list = [['my', 'fellow', 'citizens'], ['forty-four', 'americans', 'have', 'now', 'taken', 'the', 'presidential', 'oath']]
```

using

```
.strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-')
```

I was planning on creating some sort of loop through each sub-list and then through each element and assigning the stripped version of that element to the same index in new_list but when I tried to do it with an individual element
e.g.

```
clean_list[0][0] = master_list[0][0].strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-')
```

but I get

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I don't think so, the real list has 100,00s+ enteries and I just want to remove the external punctuation from each string

Comment: Did you initialize `clean_list` first?? Cause maybe that's the reason for index error as your program doesn't know what type of clean_list variable is. If not, just initialize it with `clean_list = []` then `clean_list.append(master_list[0][0].strip(...))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop.

```py
master_list = [['my', 'fellow', 'citizens.'], ['forty-four', 'americans', 'have', 'now!', 'taken', 'the', 'presidential', 'oath.']]

for i in range(len(master_list)):
    for j in range(len(master_list[i])):
        master_list[i][j] = master_list[i][j].strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-')

print(master_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is because you didn’t define clean_list

In case you don't know how many elements your nested list master_list will have you can define it like this

```
clean_list=[]
```

to add 'cleaned' elements from your master_list to clean_list you can use Python .append() Method

```
clean_list.append(master_list[0][0].strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-'))
```

in the end your coud should look something like this:

```
master_list = [['my', 'fellow', 'citizens.'], ['forty-four', 'americans', 'have', 'now!', 'taken', 'the', 'presidential', 'oath.']]

clean_list=[]
for l in master_list:
    l_ = []
    for item in l:
        l_.append(item.strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-'))
    clean_list.append(l_)

print(clean_list)
```

Comment: This resolves the error but does not maintain the structure of the original list, where the strings are in nested lists.

Comment: @ljdyer As far as I can see in the post, he don't want to change the original structure of the list, he want to create a new_list

Comment: Yes, a new list with the same structure as the original list, which is why they tried `clean_list[0][0] = master_list[0][0].strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-')`

Comment: @ljdyer 
and what structure do you think this code generates?

Comment: @ljdyer it generates exactly the same structure

Comment: Ah yep, looking good now post-edit!

Answer (score 0):

The `split` part is fine. The reason you are getting the `IndexError` is that you haven't initiated the list `clean_list`, so nothing exists in the elements you are referring to.

You can create `clean_list` by looping over the elements of `master_list` and appending values to `clean_list` as you go:

```
clean_list = []
for sublist in master_list:
    clean_sublist = []
    for s in sublist:
        clean_sublist.append(s.strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-'))
    clean_list.append(clean_sublist)
print(clean_list)
```

Or a more concise and 'Pythonic' way would be to use a nested list comprehension:

```
clean_list = [[s.strip('"!,.:;?\'/()&$-') for s in sublist] for sublist in master_list]
```